# Laravel 5 Homestead w/ Vagrant and Virtual Box white page

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

Hello fellow programmers,

So i am currently assigned to install and configure Laravel 5 with homestead and Vagrant currently i am having various issues.. for now i came across the following error in my gitbash. Before this error i had run the init.sh again because someone told me he fixed his homestead that way..
So how can i fix this error?

Oh and i am working on Windows 7.

```
Welcome to Git (version 1.9.5-preview20150319)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.


Stefano@STEFANO-PC ~/Homestead/Homestead (master)
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: homestead
The name of your virtual machine couldn't be set because VirtualBox
is reporting another VM with that name already exists. Most of the
time, this is because of an error with VirtualBox not cleaning up
properly. To fix this, verify that no VMs with that name do exist
(by opening the VirtualBox GUI). If they don't, then look at the
folder in the error message from VirtualBox below and remove it
if there isn't any information you need in there.

VirtualBox error:

VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not rename the directory 'C:\Users\Stefano\VirtualB
ox VMs\settler_default_1430450956915_11366_1431938089885_29938' to 'C:\Users\Ste
fano\VirtualBox VMs\homestead' to save the settings file (VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component SessionMachi
ne, interface IMachine, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "SaveSettings()" at line 2788 of file VBoxManage
ModifyVM.cpp


Stefano@STEFANO-PC ~/Homestead/Homestead (master)
$
```

Comment: You already did this, as stated in the error message? *To fix this, verify that no VMs with that name do exist
(by opening the VirtualBox GUI). If they don't, then look at the
folder in the error message from VirtualBox below and remove it
if there isn't any information you need in there.*

Comment: I added this as an answer so you can mark this question as solved for other users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already did this, as stated in the error message?

> *To fix this, verify that no VMs with that name do exist (by opening the VirtualBox GUI). If they don't, then look at the folder in the error message from VirtualBox below and remove it if there isn't any information you need in there.*

Answer (score 0):

I was confused by the response because I was deleting the machine form virtual box manager.  I went to the c/users/%user%/Vbox directory and deleted all the boxes and was able to reload the vbox.  I suspect all data was lost but it was a fresh install but curious how to back up the data and restore it in this situation.  (I.e. in the event I had data there I needed.)